# Using TFS Power Tool to send email to Any person who get assigned a new Work Item

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

I can use TFS Power Tools to send emails to a specific user every-time a new work item created but instead i want to send the person who is assigned the new work item!

any one has any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

This should be easy to achieve using the AlertsExplorer:
[image]
The bad thing about this, is that you need one rule for each distinct user that gets this enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you want people to get notified when a Work Item assigned to them is created/changed you have to ask them to register the "My Work Items are changed by others" alert from Visual Studio (no need to use the Power Tools).

You can't register a generic alert that will send an alert to an email address that depends on the user which get the work item assigned to. (if that's your question, but I'm not sure).

[image]

[image]